# Ebay API with Paypal IPN integration - Error 20822 - Invalid ItemID or TransactionID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, ebay-api

I'm trying to make IPN to set my item as shipped, but i get 20822 error. This is my XMLRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Version>869</Version>
    <ItemID> $item_number </ItemID>
    <TransactionID>$txn_id</TransactionID>
    <FeedbackInfo>
        <CommentText>Great transaction, great buyer!</CommentText>
        <CommentType>Positive</CommentType>
        <TargetUser>$auction_buyer_id</TargetUser>
    </FeedbackInfo>
    <Shipped>true</Shipped>
    <Paid>true</Paid>
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken> $my_token </eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</CompleteSaleRequest>
```

$auction_buyer_id, $item_number and $txn_id are from ipn, and i checked them and i think they are good.
the response from ebay look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompleteSaleResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2014-05-29T10:41:35.147Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Invalid ItemID or TransactionID</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Invalid ItemID or TransactionID</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>20822</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>873</Version>
    <Build>E873_CORE_APIXO_16844666_R1</Build>
</CompleteSaleResponse>
```

I was search on internet and i cant find solution. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: This not an IPN transaction. Please correct your post to state what API you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question

`<TransactionID>` should not be `$txn_id` (like it was in tutorials) but `$ebay_txn_id`
(i found this variable when i send all variables posted from ipn to my email end search what was there)

Comment: Can I ask about what is the ebay_txn_id?